# Using Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block with strongly typed data sets

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, strongly-typed-dataset

I want my strongly typed data sets to be database agnostic. Is it possible to use Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block with strongly typed data sets?

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of your strongly typed datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LoadDataSet` method provided by the `Database` class.  Please see the linked article below.

http://weblogs.asp.net/joshrobinson/archive/2005/03/30/396311.aspx